# Why does this setInterval function cause TypeError: n is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I can't really figure out why calling this function in a setInterval causes `TypeError: n is undefined`. Without the setInterval it works perfectly fine.

```
const getBackEndServers = () => {
  const master = {
    name: "Back-end Master Node",
    addr: "127.0.0.1:6000",
    status: "ok"
  }
  setBackEndMaster(master)

  fetch(`${rootAddr}/backendnodes`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      const servers = []
      const clusterArr = []
      if (data.status === "ok") {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.clusterNum; i++) {
          clusterArr.push(i)
          data[i].forEach((addr) => {
            servers.push({ name: `Storage server - cluster ${i}`, addr: addr, status: "ok", cluster: i })
          })
        }
        setBackEndClusterNum(clusterArr)
        setStorageServers(servers)
      }
    });
 }

  useEffect(() => {
    getBackEndServers()
    this.backendIntervalId = setInterval(() => getBackEndServers(), 5000);

    return function cleanup() {
      clearInterval(this.backendIntervalId);
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: What is this even trying to do? Usually you don't need any thing prefixed with `this` in a functional component, but you're also assigning the component itself on mount to an is value. It's difficult to understand how that makes sense.

Comment: When component mounts, I want it to run `getBackEndServers` every 5 seconds.

Comment: Yes you don't use `this.` in a functional component, store the interval in a ref with `useRef`. Also, what line specifically is causing the error, need it narrows down a bit. The error isn't too useful since it seems like it's from minified code